# expandable notificaton android 4.1

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

There is new feature in Android 4.1 JellyBean. Expandable Notifications in status bar.
Question is how to implement it ? There is any tutorial how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rather new feature. That's why there isn't much information or code samples out there (not yet).

However, this should help you for a start (including code sample):
<strike>[http://www.martynhaigh.com/blog/2012/07/31/new-notifications-in-jellybean](http://www.martynhaigh.com/blog/2012/07/31/new-notifications-in-jellybean/)</strike>

**New Link:** [JellyBean Notification test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sloy.jbnotif) (Source Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Sloy/Jelly-Bean-Notification-Test))

Apart from that, the official Google documentation is always your friend:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#UI

Comment: @jtietema I've added a new link to an example app demonstrating the new JellyBean notifications (including the source code).